# Python - Grabbing start date from first row and end date from last row by category

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following data on a list of students, the universities they have went to, the modules they have taken, as well as the start and end date of the modules (some empty values for the "End Date" to indicate that the class is still ongoing):

| Student | University | Module | Start Date of Class | End Date of Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wanda | Xavier's School for Gifted | Telekinesis | 02-Jan-2018 | 05-Feb-2018 |
| Wanda | Xavier's School for Gifted | Telepathy | 06-Feb-2018 | 10-Apr-2018 |
| Wanda | Avengers Assemble University | Flight | 01-May-2018 | 30-Jun-2018 |
| Vision | Avengers Assemble University | Flight | 01-May-2018 | 30-Jun-2018 |
| Vision | Avengers Assemble University | Density Manipulation | 01-Jul-2018 |  |
| Human Torch | Fantastic Four School | Flight | 02-Jan-2018 | 04-Apr-2018 |

Now, I want to have a table on the students' name, the school they went to, and for how long they were in that school. I don't care what module they have taken. That is, I want something like that:

| Student | University | Start Date of School | End Date of School | No. of Days in School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wanda | Xavier's School for Gifted | 02-Jan-2018 | 10-Apr-2018 | 99 |
| Wanda | Avengers Assemble University | 01-May-2018 | 30-Jun-2018 | 61 |
| Vision | Avengers Assemble University | 01-May-2018 | NA | Ongoing |
| Human Torch | Fantastic Four School | 02-Jan-2018 | 04-Apr-2018 | 93 |

What is the best way to achieve this? I've tried the following on Python after much trial and error, but I thought such method seems overly convoluted even though it worked:

1. Do a .groupby(['Student', 'University', 'Module'])
2. Do a .head(1) and .tail(1) on my output from 1., concat them and remove duplicates (so that students with only one record like Human Torch is not duplicated from the .head(1) and .tail(1))
3. Introduce one column each for ['student'].shift(-1), ['University'].shift(-1), ['Module'].shift(-1), and ['End Date of Class'].shift(-1)
4. Create a function that goes: if (['student'] == ['student'].shift(-1)) AND (['University'] ==['University'].shift(-1)) AND (['Module'] == ['Module'].shift(-1)), then ['End Date of School'] = ['End Date of Class'].shift(-1). Else, ['End Date of School'] = ['End Date of Class']. Apply the function (duh~).
5. Do a .head(1) again on the output from 4., drop the column ['End Date of Class'], and rename the column ['Start Date of Class'] into ['Start Date of School']. Calculate the number of days from these two dates. Also, drop all the many .shift(-1) columns created as a stepping stone

That is a lot of lines of codes for something straightforward that I wanted to get. Any suggestions on a more direct method that can be used here?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use a `groupby` and a named aggregation, then compute the number of days:

```
dg = df.groupby(['Student ', 'University '])[['Start Date of Class ','End Date of Class']].agg(
        {'Start Date of Class ': 'min', 'End Date of Class': 'max'}).reset_index()
dg['No. of Days in School'] = dg['End Date of Class'] - dg['Start Date of Class '] + 1
```

It gives:

```
       Student                     University  Start Date of Class  End Date of Class No. of Days in School
0  Human Torch          Fantastic Four School            2018-01-02        2018-04-04               93 days
1       Vision   Avengers Assemble University            2018-05-01        2018-09-30              153 days
2        Wanda   Avengers Assemble University            2018-05-01        2018-06-30               61 days
3        Wanda     Xavier's School for Gifted            2018-01-02        2018-04-10               99 days
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about named aggregation. But what if I have some empty / null values for the "End Date of Class" (e.g. the class is still ongoing)? The aggregation on the max date would not work then. Apologies for not including this detail in my question earlier.

Comment: @user13399233: A trick would be to fill the missing end values with a date. Either the expected end of the school year if you want *sensible* values or a date far in the future (more than 1 year). Then you replace with NaT this date, and the no of days greater than 365 (use 10 years and 3650 if you can have longer school cycles)